# How to dual boot windows 7 and windows 10 using easybcd. (missing media drive)

Tags: windows, dualboot, easybcd

I heard we can dual boot windows 10 and windows 7 using easybcd(WITHOUT USB). But I am unable to install windows 10 as a dual boot. A PROBLEM occurs. It is about missing usb and hard drives.How to fix it. My motherboard is gygabyte.

Comment: You need to reframe your question; completely unclear what issue you are facing and please be specific when telling specs; also mention bios mode; Also it's never a good idea to use buggy third party tools like this; you should first install win 10 and then win 7 ; also keep in mind win 7 doesn't support uefi

Comment: It is actually running perfect when i run setup.exe. Actually i am trying to dual 32 bit to 64 bit. But it is not letting me to run bc it is 64 bit application. And my pc has 32 bit windows. Btw with 64 bit processor. I heard we can dual boot 32 bit and 64 bit easily. But i am unable to do this. Thats why i used third party software :(

Comment: By buggy third party.. I have been using this tool since 2006 @Madhubala and never had a problem.  Sometimes Microsoft doesn't provide tools needed to get the job done.  Just look at partition management.  Windows 7 does support UEFI if the firmware has INT10 support.  And you are completely right that this question is written poorly and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, you would probably be better off with a virtualbox or hyper-v Windows 7 VM running on a windows 10 host.  These days, running a VM is *almost* seamless.  In full screen mode, I can't even tell that I am in a VM.